# Create an array having random numbers (each number being less than 100) with length n

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to programming world.. can anyone help me please.

I need to write a program that gets an input number 'n', which is an arbitrary number. than, create an array with length 'n' that contains random numbers (each number being less than 100). Output all the numbers within the array as comma separated, 5 numbers at a line.

Comment: Here's some friendly advice: Do some research of your own on how to code your program before rushing here. When things don't work, you can come back with a specific question concerning **your code**. We're not a 'do my work for me' community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your question in order to make it  more clear so you'll get the help you want.
I guess you were trying to get a number from the user, than create an 'array' of that number size. Afterwards you want to assign random 'int', ranging 0-100 (100 exclusive), for each array index. IN the end output the array values comma separated, 5 in each line.
I wrote a code to do that:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // import Scanner object to get user input

public class ArrRandomNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // initialize Scanner object 'input'.
        System.out.print("Enter a number: "); // prompt.
        int n = input.nextInt(); // parse and assign the next int. use lowercase for variables.
        input.close(); // close Scanner object 'input' to avoid resource leaks.

        int[] arr = new int[n]; // initialize array 'arr' of size 'n'.

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100); // assign random int 0-100 (100 exclusive)

        }

        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {

            System.out.printf("%d, ", arr[j]); // print arr[j] value and a ', '.

            if ((j+1) % 5 == 0) { // every 5 numbers goes down a line.

                System.out.println();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yesss exactly.. sorry to be not clearly asked.. i was confused :P tnxx buddy

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember Java syntax off the topic of my head but it should be something like:

```
// create an array of type 'int' I am guessing and of size 'N'
int[] array = new int[N]; 

// get random number for each array
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   array[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
}
// print them
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");// println will print each array value in a new line.

   if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0) {
       System.out.println(); // go down a line every 5 number printed.
}
```

My syntax might be off but you'll get the general idea. Not sure what you mean about

> Now show all the numbers within the array as comma separated, 5 at a
>   time.

Comment: tnxxxxxxxxx i got the idea how to do.. tnx a lot :) @sacert

Comment: yes u edited @NitzanM .. i already used N in the  loop instead of 100.. lolzz tnxx i just want to get some idea .. tnxx a lot